# How to convert or integrate my java web based application in Jira plugin?

Tags: java, spring, jira, jira-plugin

I am working on one Java Spring web based application with Angular 2 in front-end, I want to integrate it with Jira plugin for front-end Angular it is successfully integrated using "atlassian-scanner". And I can see my login page inside Jira but for login and other request it is not working as back-end in not working properly.

My "webpack-manifest.xml" looks like as below :

```
<bundles>
<web-resource key="client-resources" name="Client Resources">
    <resource name="3rdpartylicenses.txt" type="download" location="client/3rdpartylicenses.txt" />
    <resource name="layers.png" type="download" location="client/layers.png" />
    <resource name="layers-2x.png" type="download" location="client/layers-2x.png" />
            <context>atl.general</context>
</web-resource>
</bundles>
```

and for Integrating my application I have added below configuration in "atlassian-plugin.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<atlassian-plugin key="${atlassian.plugin.key}" name="${project.name}" plugins-version="2"> 
  <plugin-info> 
    <description>${project.description}</description>  
    <version>${project.version}</version>  
    <vendor name="${project.organization.name}" url="${project.organization.url}"/>  
    <param name="plugin-icon">images/pluginIcon.png</param>  
    <param name="plugin-logo">images/pluginLogo.png</param> 
  </plugin-info>  
  <!-- add our i18n resource -->  
  <resource type="i18n" name="i18n" location="ngdemo"/>
  <resource type="download" name="assets/" location="client/assets/"/>
<servlet-context-param key="camelconfig">
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:camel-config.xml</param-value>
  </servlet-context-param>

  <servlet-context-listener name="Hello World Listener" key="helloWorld" class="org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener">
  </servlet-context-listener>

  <servlet name="CamelServlet" i18n-name-key="camel-servlet.name" key="camel-servlet" class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet">
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-filter name="CustomFilter" key="customFilter" class="com.filter.CustomFilter" location="before-dispatch" weight="200">
  <url-pattern>/demo/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-filter>
  <resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" maxTotal="30" maxIdle="10" maxWaitMillis="10000" minIdle="5" name="jdbc/DBname" username="postgres" password="ROOT" url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

</atlassian-plugin>
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.templaterenderer</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-template-renderer-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jta</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-annotation</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jira-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.2</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <compressResources>false</compressResources>
                    <productVersion>${jira.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${jira.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <!-- Uncomment to install TestKit backdoor in JIRA. -->
                    <!--
                    <pluginArtifacts>
                        <pluginArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jira-testkit-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
                        </pluginArtifact>
                    </pluginArtifacts>
                    -->
                    <enableQuickReload>true</enableQuickReload>
                    <!-- See here for an explanation of default instructions: -->
                    <!-- https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/advanced-topics/configuration-of-instructions-in-atlassian-plugins -->
                    <instructions>
                        <Atlassian-Plugin-Key>${atlassian.plugin.key}</Atlassian-Plugin-Key>
                        <!-- Add package to export here -->
                        <Export-Package>com.demo.api,</Export-Package>
                        <!-- Add package import here -->
                        <Import-Package>org.springframework.osgi.*;resolution:="optional", org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.*;resolution:="optional", *</Import-Package>
                        <!-- Ensure plugin is spring powered -->
                        <Spring-Context>*</Spring-Context>
                        <Atlassian-Scan-Folders>META-INF/plugin-descriptor</Atlassian-Scan-Folders>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${atlassian.spring.scanner.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>atlassian-spring-scanner</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scannedDependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>atlassian-spring-scanner-external-jar</artifactId>
                        </dependency>
                    </scannedDependencies>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <jira.version>7.13.0</jira.version>
        <amps.version>8.0.2</amps.version>
        <plugin.testrunner.version>2.0.1</plugin.testrunner.version>
        <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
        <!-- This property ensures consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the OSGi bundle's key. -->
        <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <!-- TestKit version 6.x for JIRA 6.x -->
        <testkit.version>6.3.11</testkit.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

And I have added all external jars inside "Project Structure" -> "Libraries" in Intellij but it seems like this is not working properly.

Do anyone have idea how to properly integrate our application inside Jira or have any proper documentation step by step? Your help will be really grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does your pom.xml look like? And what does "not working properly" mean?

Comment: @tgdavies thank you for the response, I have added pom.xml in question, and what is happening our application we have some external jars that I have added directly in Libraries not via "pom.xml" as some don't have maven dependencies  and also rest requests but while starting jira pulgin it seems it is not considering this external jars and also out application in not getting deployed in jira plugin, I have added our servlet config in  "atlassian-plugin.xml" but nowt working, so how to deploy our application in Jira Plugin.

Comment: Here are a few clues. The video is a little dated (replace "Flow" with "TypeScript" and you probably want to use webpack directly instead of gulp), but it covers some of the basic concepts.

WRM webpack plugin: https://bitbucket.org/atlassianlabs/fe-server/src/master/packages/webresource-webpack-plugin/
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pIudmkpHh0

Comment: Dependencies are only going to be included in the plugin jar if maven knows about them. You should add those dependencies to your pom and either install them to your local repo (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html) or use `system` scope for those dependencies in your pom.

Comment: @tgdavies ohky so I have to add all my external jars using maven right? but what about my application how do I integrate/deploy it in jira plugin tomcat? Sorry as I am new to Jira so not getting cleared.

Comment: @ScottDudley thank you for the response but my front-end is integrated properly but I am stuck at back-end java application which runs on tomcat and I need to run it with jira plugin tomcat.

Comment: You're going to need to rewrite components of your back end and declare them in atlassian-plugin.xml using the module types that are supported by Jira, and then point them at the relevant classes. If you still need more assistance, I would suggest being much more specific about what "does not work".

Comment: @ScottDudley, yes I am getting your point but after converting all my jars to local maven and adding it now when we start Jira plugin it shows GC get over exceed

Comment: At this point, I’d recommend creating a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)